# Speech Recognition opening multiple tabs?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I am trying to make a speech recognition with commands and the basic commands work but when I try use the commands that involve searching with websites it opens multiple tabs at once and some of the links have fragments of the main search.

I have tried adding a break once it opens the first link but it wont stop the loop and I added a wait to let the script load the text before it opens it in a new tab.

```
// tables
const commandTable = {
    "gmail": () => window.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/'),
    "youtube": (query) => window.open(`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${query}`),
    "google": (query) => window.open(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${query}`),
    "chrome": (query) => window.open(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${query}`),
};

const defautlLinks = {
    "youtube": () => window.open(`https://www.youtube.com`),
    "google": () => window.open(`https://www.google.com`),
    "chrome": () => window.open(`https://www.google.com`),
}

// values
let commandExecuted = false;
let commandPosition = 0;

// functions
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    speechCheck()
});

// ...

async function speechCheck() {
    const userText = document.getElementById('userText');
    const speechRecognition = window.speechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
    const recognition = new speechRecognition();

    recognition.lang = 'en';
    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.interimResults = true;

    recognition.start();

    recognition.onresult = async (event) => {
        const last = event.results.length - 1;
        const text = event.results[last][0].transcript;
        const lowerCaseText = text.toLowerCase();
        const finalText = lowerCaseText.split(" ");

        userText.textContent = text;

        if (!commandExecuted) {
            for (let i = 0; i < finalText.length; i++) {
                if (!commandExecuted) {
                    const word = finalText[i].toLowerCase();
                if (word === "open") {
                    commandPosition = i;
                }
                if (word === "open" && commandTable[finalText[i + 1]]) {
                    commandTable[finalText[i + 1]]();
                    commandExecuted = true;
                    await commandState();
                    break;
                }
                if (word === "google" || word === "chrome" || word === "youtube") {
                    const commandWord = i;
                    let query = "";

                    await wait(1.5);
                    for (let j = commandPosition + 1; j < commandWord; j++) {
                        const newWord = finalText[j];
                        query += newWord + " ";
                    }
                    query = query.trim();

                    if (query === "") {
                        defautlLinks[word]();
                        await commandState();
                        break
                    } else {
                        commandTable[word](query);
                        commandExecuted = true;
                        await commandState();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    recognition.onerror = () => {
        userText.textContent = "I'm sorry I didn't quite get that";
    }
}

// ...


async function commandState() {
    await wait(2);
    commandExecuted = false;
}

async function wait(time) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time * 1000));
}
```

I have tried looking on youtube and google but found nothing.